# How to link two Do While loop together?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create two iterations here. First part is "For i=1 to iterations". Second part is "j" from 1 to 731.

In the code, P1, P2, P3 are constant, Discrete1, Discrete2,Discrete3 are functions, but will return integers randomly.

in VBA, I can run the code, but the results return wrongly due to some reasons.

What I would like to achieve is that when j less than 266, it goes with first loop, when j is between 360 to 731, then, it goes with second loop.

Anyone could help? I would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
For i = 1 To Iteration:    Cells(4, 3) = i

Do While j < 366

        If IIf(Rnd() < P1, 1, 0) = 1 Then
            RestorationDay1 = Discrete1
        ElseIf IIf(Rnd() < P2, 1, 0) = 1 Then
            RestorationDay1 = Discrete2
        ElseIf IIf(Rnd() < P3, 1, 0) = 1 Then
            RestorationDay1 = Discrete3
        Else
            RestorationDay1 = 0
        End If

        Sumunavailableday1 = Sumunavailableday1 + RestorationDay1
        unAvailability1 = Sumunavailableday1 / 365
        Availability1 = 1 - unAvailability1

        Cells(4, 8) = j
        Cells(4, 9) = Availability1
        Cells(4, 10) = unAvailability1
        Cells(4, 11) = Sumunavailableday1

        j = j + RestorationDay1 + 1


Loop

Do While 365 < j < 731

        If IIf(Rnd() < P1, 1, 0) = 1 Then
            RestorationDay2 = Discrete1
        ElseIf IIf(Rnd() < P2, 1, 0) = 1 Then
            RestorationDay2 = Discrete2
        ElseIf IIf(Rnd() < P3, 1, 0) = 1 Then
            RestorationDay2 = Discrete3
        Else
            RestorationDay2 = 0
        End If

        Sumunavailableday2 = Sumunavailableday2 + RestorationDay2
        unAvailability2 = Sumunavailableday2 / 365
        Availability2 = 1 - unAvailability2

        Cells(5, 8) = j
        Cells(5, 9) = Availability2
        Cells(5, 10) = unAvailability2
        Cells(5, 11) = Sumunavailableday2

        j = j + RestorationDay2 + 1
Loop
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in your description and your code do not match.

This will fix your second loop.

> Do While (j > 365) And (j < 731)

You have a particular way of coding.  I'm guessing it comes from your background in mathematics.  In any case, I would use `Rnd() >= P1` instead of `IIf(Rnd() < P1, 1, 0) = 1`.  I think that it is more straight forward.  It looks like you're trying to make a random two year availability schedule.  If so you might want to change your loop to evaluate dates. This way you wouldn't have to account for leap years.

Loop 1

> Do While Year(DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, j )) = Year(Date())

Loop 2

> Do While Year(DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, j )) = Year(Date()) + 1

Comment: Thanks very much, Thomas, I have tried your first suggestion. It works.  Re your second suggestion: I would agree with you, Rnd()>=P1 would be much easier. However, both way are not actually random, I decided to use another function to replace the Rnd() by adding extra line: Randomize.

Comment: For your two new loops, I would think about it as I dont fully understand the meaning of function as VBA is still quite new to me, I will have a go and follow up later on. Thanks again!:)